# Difference between frame and image?

Tags: image-processing, terminology, video-processing

This term'Frame' is often used in image processing for frame rate, but is there any difference between an image and a frame?

Comment: not an expert on these topics, but "frame" is something you'd encounter when dealing with video and means the thing happening "on screen" at a specific time instance, "image" is more general.

Comment: Could you please review my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Frame is the element in the time index of a video.
For 2D videos, each frame is an image.

Frame Rate is just the sampling frequency of the time index of the video.